# Ionic 2 : Background mode error

Tags: angular, typescript, background, ionic2

I try to use this for Ionic 2 : 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/

I ran the two command

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-mode
```

And I tried to declare the provider in my app.module.ts :

```
import {BackgroundMode} from "@ionic-native/background-mode";
 providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    ...
      BackgroundMode
    ...
  ]
```

But when I run it on my device I have this error :

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(140848)] "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "@ionic-native/core"", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (140848)
```

And an infite white screen on my device.

I tried to use it without declare in my app.module.ts and directly in my component but I had same error...

Someone know how to solve it ?

Comment: can you add package.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `@ionic-native/background-mode` it means you are using `ionic-native 3.x`.

You need to do:

```
npm install @ionic-native/core --save
```

Also you no longer need the `ionic-native 2.x` package.
You can remove it from your package.json in case you have it.

Check the main page of [ionic-native docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/)